# Create New Feature_ID following Series of numbers

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, query, point-of-interest, order

I have two datasets of data let say set_1 and set_2. set_1 is original dataset and set_2 is modified dataset (duplicates and wrong data has been removed from the data).
Due to the modification some of the data has been removed from the set_2. Now i am adding few more new features to the data. so i want new ids for the new features.
[image]

if i use $id the features id's i have already deleted in set_2 will again regenerated. if i vlook up data from the set_1 in case the data wont join correctly. thats why i dont want any of the id which are in the set_1 should not repeat. thats why i want new ids for my new features................hope you understand my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you created your data. However, the behaviour is not normal. Normally, you should not need to care about the id this way, as QGIS would handle this automatically the way you want. Saving your data as Geopackage, you automatically get a `fid` that exactly does what you describe.

So you probably miss a point here, but you don't provide enough information to see what goes wrong. Still, to answer your question in case you really want to continue to do this manually using the following expression (see below for explanation). Be aware: in my case, `fid` is the name of the id-value in `Set_1`; in `Set_2` it's called `id` (change this accordingly):

```
if (
    "id" is NULL,
    aggregate ('Set_1', 'max', "fid") +
    @row_number -
    array_length ( 
        aggregate( 
            @layer,
            'array_agg',
            "id", 
            filter:= "id" is not NULL
        )
    ),
    "id"
)
```

[image]

1. Find the largest existing id value in Set_1 with `aggregate( 'Set_1','max',fid)`. In your screenshot, this would return `8`.
2. Find the number of remaining features (rows, lines) that already have an id value in `Set_2` with `array_length (array_agg ("id", filter:= "id" is not NULL))`. Returns `6` in your example.
3. Now for each of the additional rows (lines 7, 8,...), calculate a sequential series of how much you have to add: add 1 for line 7, 2 for line 8 etc. To calculate this, use `@row_number - [result from step 2]` - replace the part in angular braces `[]` with the expression from step 2.
4. You want to start with id=9 (next larger value from step 1) in line 7 (next feature from step 2). Thus add value from step 1 with value from step 3.
5. You want to update only id's that are empty, but keep pre existing values

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the new features. You can use Select by Expression with `fid is NULL`.
2. Run Field calculator and check the box next to `Only update [n] selected features`.

---

*You could even update `$id` for all fid fields, including those that already have a fid value. If this pre existing fid is based on `$id`, it will return the same value as before.*

[image]

Comment: cant we continue the series from 996

Comment: numbers are repeated in this case makes feature duplicate. can't we continue the series from the last id @babel

Comment: Using $id you should get automatically an autoincrement number that starts from the last id you have, thus from 996 in your case. If for some reason that should not be the case, then the question is: how was this fid generated? What does it represent? In this case, you can add 996 to the $id and use this expression: `$id + 996`

Comment: when using $id it calculates the id's with the help of FID which is already existing. I dont want any of the Ids created with the help of any other columns @babel

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean... If you don't want to re-calculate the `fid`, then make it like I described it in the solution and only fid's that don't already exist will be created.

Comment: i just edited my question please look in to the issue.

Comment: And what is the problem to select only the new features and create fid only for them? Sorry, still don't understand. Can you add a screenshot or share data+project?

Comment: @ babel i have added the screenshot please check once...

Comment: See new answer that should solve the problem. However, I thin you over-complicate things. You don't tell us how you create set_2 and why $id does not work: normally (at least if you have saved the layer as Geopackage), QGIS will handle this automatically exact the way you want it. So I don't understand why this does not work in your case as there is information missing from your part.